# Current Cursor Position when Using the Prawn Ruby Library

Tags: ruby, prawn

I'm using the Prawn Ruby library (http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/) to generate some pdf documents.  I draw a table without any problem.  Next, I want to insert some lines after the table for various people's signatures.  Before I draw the lines, I would like to see if there is enough remaining room on the page to fit all the signatures.  If not, I will start a new page and put the signature lines there.  However, in order to determine if enough room remains on the page, I need to know what the current cursor position is after drawing the table.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of course, after entering the question, I immediately figure it out.  The 'y' and 'y=' methods in the Document class allow you to get and set the current y position, which is all that is necessary.

Comment: I don't see `#y` in the Document class, only `#y=`.    I was using `pdf.cursor` inside my document to view the cursor's current position.